# Three.js - collada model not loading when specifying a texture

Tags: three.js, collada

I try to load a converted collada model (obj -> collada [opens without a problem in max, including working uvs]) with the three.js collada loader. The model was converted using assimp, an open source 3d model converter.

A thing I noticed is that the converted collada model has children inside children but I heard that would be no problem. However if I change the material to something with a texture, I get an error: "TypeError: uv2i is undefined".

As long as I do not use a texture the model loads.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2705276/bachelorShowcases/001/webGL_museum_wire.html

Model not loading when specifying a texture:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2705276/bachelorShowcases/001/webGL_museum.html

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
function load( model ){

loader.load( 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2705276/bachelorShowcases/001/xerox404_webglCONV.dae', createScene1 );

}

function createScene1( geometry ) {

dae = geometry.scene;
mesh = dae.children[0].children[0];
mesh.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2705276/bachelorShowcases/001/xeroxD.png')});

}
```

Comment: The viewer/navigator loads but I don't see anything in your preview link.

Comment: yes that's the problem. if i do not specify a texture the object loads. Here is a test with a wireframe only shader: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2705276/bachelorShowcases/001/webGL_museum_wire.html

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console you'll see this error:

```
webGL_museum.html:461
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'u' of undefined three.js:17814
```

That basically means that your model doesn't have UVs. In order to use a texture with a model it needs to have UVs.

Comment: hello Mr.Doob, thanks for your reply. The strange thing is: if I take the exact same model and open it in 3ds Max I can apply a texture to it without a problem. Using the unwrap uvw modifier i can see the uvs exactly as i generated them.